New Ender 3 huge problems
I just got an Ender 3 V2 for my birthday.
I managed to get three prints before it stopped working properly the tube melted clogging the system.
Now when I print it won't stick to the bed and keeps building up around the tip.
I tried leveling the bed nonstop about 10 times now all four corners are good but the center seems to be lower somehow. PETG used settings all correct.



If the z-offset setting in your slicer is a positive non-zero number, try lowering it.

its whatever it is by default.

But what is it?

G28 ;Home
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to start position
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15 ;Draw the first line
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to side a little
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30 ;Draw the second line
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
